# how to convert laravel query

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent

(select business_name from clients where id = orders.main_client_id) as b_name

This above sql query and I am converted sql to laravel type is right or wrong because this below query give me output [][][] this type any suggestion..

```php
->addColumn('business_name', function($data) {
        
     $b_name = DB::table("clients")
       ->select("business_name")
       ->where('clients.id','main_client_id')
       ->get();
     return $b_name;                 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You left out the comparison symbol (=)

```
$b_name = DB::table('clients')
    ->where('id', '=', 'main_client_id')
    ->get();
```

or

```
$b_name = DB::table('clients')
    ->where('clients.id', '=', 'main_client_id')
    ->value('business_name');
```

Comment: business_name value come in NULL

->addColumn('business_name', function($data) {
        
                    $b_name = DB::table("clients")
                            ->select("business_name")
                            ->where('clients.id','=','orders.main_client_id')
                            ->value('business_name');
                    return $b_name;
                })

Comment: This is unnecessary. Comparison parameter is optional when you want to use "="

Comment: exactly @Psycho

Comment: So, your answer is not what the questioner is looking for

Comment: exactly what are you looking for? 
Have you done the sql query, in DBeaver or navicat to test?
If you want clients.id to be the same as main_client_id you have to use the symbol = normally

Answer (score 0):

you are comparing with column value not mere value, so you have to use [whereColumn](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#additional-where-clauses):

```
->addColumn('business_name', function($data) {
        
     $b_name = DB::table("clients")
       ->select("business_name")
       ->whereColumn('clients.id','main_client_id')
       ->get();
     return $b_name;                 
});
```